# How to save big data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, shell, debian, mariadb

I have a lot of big text files, that i want to safe in my database. I have written a shell script which can safe a small amount of data, but when i try it with some big files i get following error:

```
mysql: Argument list too long
```

The column content has the type longtext.

test.txt has 60 words in it and safes content.
If I try the same with austen-emma.txt(which has 158167 words) I get the described error.

```
#!/bin/sh

content=`cat /srv/data/english_gutenberg_corpus/test.txt`

db_value=`mysql -u admin -padmin --database=bp12 -e "INSERT INTO db_connector_text (author, date, genre, content, title, language, source, wordlength) VALUES ('lel', '1970-01-16', 'NULL', '$content', 'Lyrische elemente', 'German', 'kp', 20)"`
```

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`/bin/sh` has a limitation on command size, perhaps a mere 5KB.  Switch to some other way of dealing with the data.  Regardless of what database approach you ultimately take, you will need to learn a programming language (Perl, Java, VB, etc) to do the work in.

You could stick with `sh` if you use the `LOAD_FILE` function in MySQL, but I don't recommend it for anything non-trivial.

> a lot of big text files

What will you do with the files?  Display them on a web page?  Manipulate them with some program?  Provide hyperlinks to them?  Analyze them for word structure?  Other?

> i want to safe in my database

Please define "safe".  "Secure", as in protected from onlookers?  "Crash-safe", as in still there after your server dies?  "Protected from alteration", as with file permissions?  Other?

Comment: I have now written a little python program. There I have no problemen to store the data in a temp variable.

Comment: @Levo - be sure to 'escape' or 'bind' so that you don't get syntax errors during the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using a Relational Database to store large different sized files.

Best would be using a NoSQL database such as Google's Firebase etc.

https://firebase.google.com

Comment: But we need for other aspect a Relational Database. Furthermore the data we have will not be over 30 GB.

Comment: @Levo - `LONGTEXT` is limited to 4GB.  (Actually, some other limits make it difficult to get much past 16MB.)

Comment: You could always have two databases, you are not limited to one per application :)